# output of query inside forEach loop

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a query using forEach loop in mongoDB.
I want the output of query written inside forEach loop but not getting any output for inner query.
Can anyone guide how to write such query.
Below is what I have written

This query gets the very previous record of the current row with some condition.

Trying to achieve the below

Query the whole collection on given condition ie `{"INTENT_IDENTIFIED":true}`
Loop though the all the selected documents
Get the previous document of the each document in the above results
The condition of the previous document is _id is less than current _id
And the `USER_ID` is same.

```
db.bothistories.find({"INTENT_IDENTIFIED":true}).limit(100).forEach(function(doc) {
  print(doc._id)
  print(doc.USER_ID)
  db.bothistories.find({$and:[{"_id":{$lt: doc._id}},{"USER_ID":doc.USER_ID}]},{"USER_ID":1,"DATA":1}).limit(1)
})
```

I am getting values for both the print.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? you are querying same collection in both find()..

Comment: But I am taking the vales from the for each list

Comment: merge both find() condition in one query , i think that would be more efficient

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I need to find the previous row of the foreach query result each row. If it can be done in same query kindly post answer or provide your suggestion.

Comment: To print the output of the query inside the `forEach` - add the `.forEach( printjson )` to the end of the `find`query (after the `limit(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

.foreach(printjson) should do it

```
db.bothistories.find({"INTENT_IDENTIFIED":true}).limit(100).forEach(function(doc) {
  print(doc._id)
  print(doc.USER_ID)
  db.bothistories.find({$and:[{"_id":{$lt: doc._id}},{"USER_ID":doc.USER_ID}]},{"USER_ID":1,"DATA":1}).limit(1).forEach(printjson)
})
```